# Method of Moment Estimator of Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

The sample r.v. $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ i.i.d. $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, find the moment estimator of $P\{X>1\}$, where $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Here is my answer. I want to know whether it is right, thx. 
Note that $\hat \mu = \bar X, \hat{\sigma^2} = S^2.$ 
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\{X>1\} &= \int_1^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} {\rm e}^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} {\rm d}x \\
&= 1 - \Phi(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} {\rm e}^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} {\rm d}t$. 
Then I substitute $\hat \mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ to right hand side, hence moment estimator is
$$
\hat {P\{X>1\}} = 1 - \Phi(\frac{1 - \bar X}{S})
$$

Thanks to the comment.
My textbook gives $\hat{\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2$.

Comment: Essentially yes, but you need to use the method of moments to find $S^2$

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I am not sure $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2$ is a method of moments estimator

Comment: Yes, $\frac 1 {n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$ does not be a method of moments estimation. For normal distribution, we have $Var(X) = \sigma^2$, so $\hat{\sigma^2}$ should be $\frac1n \sum(X_i - \bar X)^2$, but 
$$
E\frac 1 n \sum(X_i - \bar X)^2 = \frac{n-1}{n} \sigma^2
$$
to make $\hat{\sigma^2}$ unbiased, my textbook revises it to 
$$
\hat{\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum(X_i - \bar X)^2
$$

Comment: It is your question, and you say "method of moment estimator" in the title

Comment: The parametric function $P_{\mu,\sigma}(X_1>1)$ is the mean of the indicator variable $I(X_1>1)$, so it makes sense to incorporate this into your answer for a method of moments estimator.